# NVD3: How to get values from tooltip or legend instead of labels?

Tags: d3.js, label, tooltip, legend, nvd3.js

- The problem with using labels is that if a slice is too small the labels doesn't shows up and therefore, getting the value of label during onClick event fails
- The problem is reproduced here http://plnkr.co/edit/3rCHWnxW7EFPXxWHLo96?p=preview. You will see that for **Taxes** the label is missing and therefore I can't get its value on click event
  [image]

**what would be awesome?**

- If I can get the value from tooltip or legend instead of labels because labels are not a good idea to get values
- Because I pass the value of label onclick to display other graph

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 144-145 of your script.js, you can change this:

```
.on('click', function(){
  var parentCategory = this.getElementsByClassName("nv-label")[0].textContent;
```

to this:

```
.on('click', function(d){
  var parentCategory = d.data.label;
```

This way, you are passing in the `__data__` of the clicked element to the click function, which you can access with `d`. This should solve your issue. You can also throw a `console.log(d)` within that function to see all the options available on the `__data__` object.